# Nodejs/Mongoose fetch individual data with routes. [MongoDB]

Tags: node.js

Im trying to find the cleartext for a certain hash with making a get including the hash in the link.

This code only fetches the data from the given id

```
router.get('/:id', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const md5 = await MD5.findById(req.params.id)
        res.json(md5);
    } catch (err){
        res.status(500).json({ message: err.message })
    }
})
```

GET Request

```
http://localhost:3000/md5/5ecd8e223ec4a031bccb299b
```

Output

```
{"cleartext":"softking","hash":"1e055704bb253ab362b3563902e88fe8","_id":"5ecd8e223ec4a031bccb299b"}
```

My goal is to make a get request with a hash to find the cleartext instead of requesting with a id. Sorry that I can't explain better, Im a newbie in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to pass the `hash` as a parameter to your get request. Then, you can use `find` method instead of `findById` provided by `mongoose`

```
router.get('/:hash', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const md5 = await MD5.find({hash:req.params.hash});
        res.json(md5);
    } catch (err){
        res.status(500).json({ message: err.message });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I've already tried that with "req.params.hash" instead of "hash:req.params.hash" what a silly mistake. It works finally, have a good day.

Comment: You've tried passing `req.params.hash` to the method `findById` which is wrong! Also,Glad you resolved your issue.